# The constructor's member initializer list can't include superclass's members?

Tags: c++, constructor

I've been programming C++ for decades and never expected this limitation.

Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?  I guess I need to make the `X()` constructor take an argument for i and let that constructor initialize it?  What can the point of this weird limitation possibly be?  I can understand forbidding us from initializing an object *twice*, but it's not initialized at all!  (Or, I guess in the absence of an explicit constructor, X's constructor will give it a default initialization?)  And yet:

```
class X {
public:
  X() {};
  int i;
};



class X1 : public X {
public:
  X1() : i(1){};
};
```

results in error:

```
initial.cpp: In constructor 'X1::X1()':
initial.cpp:11:10: error: class 'X1' does not have any field named 'i'
     X1() : i(1){};
            ^
```

Comment: The initialization of `X`'s members like `i` belongs to `X`. Otherwise you could potentially initalize member multiple times. Compiler cannot detect if it actually would be initialized multiple times or not. And sice the solution is to simply provide `X` constructor, I doubt anyone will bother looking into possibility of changing that.

Comment: The construction of an `X1` always calls a constructor of `X`, whether that is explicitly coded or not.    In this case, the default constructor of `X` (which accepts no arguments) is implicitly called by the default constructor of `X1`, and that (in yoru code) default-initialises `X::i`.   That constructor has the role of initialising `X`s members.   So, if `X1`s constructor was somehow allowed to initialise `X::i` directly, the result would logically be initialising `X::i` twice.

Comment: @Peter But, what are the drawbacks if we initialize X::i twice ? Seems OK in some cases

Comment: @WoooHaaaa it would invalidate whole idea of "order of initialization" and everything that relies on such within language definitions. It does nothing it this case, but what if 'i" is a complex object that creates other objects, have side effects, ownership, etc? "Some cases"  turn into whole subpoena of exclusions within 300+ pages of language rules, if allowed to be done in the way above. If you unconcerned by costs, just do `X1()  { i = 1; };`. Ideologically incorrect but allowed if `i` is public or protected.

Comment: @WoooHaaaa - It may be okay in some cases.   There are numerous cases where it doesn't, such as where initialisation of `X::i` has side effects.   In any event, semantically every object (including a member of an object) is initialised only once.   Changing that to allow particular cases where multiple initialisation doesn't matter would make the rules related to order of initialisation significantly more complicated, for little advantage.

Comment: As an aside, and purely for my own education.. . Why the ';' after X() {} ? Is it needed by some compilers: in VC++ I always seem to be able to do without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's meant to be as initialization of object is a part of that objects creation, you either have to provide initialization via X, or redesign to be able initialize it directly:

```
class X {
public:
  X() {};
  X(int _i) : i(_i) {};
  int i;
};
```

or

```
class X {
public:
  int i;
};
```

so you can do this:

```
class X1 : public X {
public:
  X1() : X{1}{};
};
```

Allowing what you tried to do would imply that we had to insert a new initialization behavior into  existing sequence, which could be compiled already as part of different compilation unit or to allow that member be initialized twice. Former is problematic to implement with whole concept of C++ implementation as native compilers, the latter makes sequence of initialization non-linear and contradicting existing ideology.

Note, that usually *composition* is *preferable* to *inheritance* if you target storage area instead of behaviour, i.e.

```
InterfaceX {
// declarations to be used in descendants
};

class X1 : public InterfaceX
{
  X   m_x;
public:
  X1() : m_x{1} {};
};
```

If we actually require polymorphic use, we'd use `InterfaceX` for virtual methods. And if we would need to "cut down" X1 to X, there need to be an conversion operator  `operator X () {return m_x; }`